# $\text{Mat}_n(R)$ is $K$-algebra $\Rightarrow$ $R$ is $K$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $K$ be a field.

> *Claim.* The centre of $\text{Mat}_n(R)$ is $Z(\text{Mat}_n(R))=Z(R)\cdot I_n$ and if $\text{Mat}_n(R)$ is a $K$-algebra, so is $R$.

*Remark.* We have defined a $K$-algebra as a ring $S$ together with a ringhomomorphism $K\rightarrow Z(S)$.

I am done with the first part of the claim.

My question is the second part of the claim. I have a ringhomomorphism $K\rightarrow\text{Mat}_n(R)$ and I want to get a ringhomomorphism $K\rightarrow R$. That would show $\text{Mat}_n(R)$ is $K$-algebra $\Rightarrow$ $R$ is $K$-algebra.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assumption, we have a morphism
$$K\xrightarrow\phi Z(\text{Mat}_n(R))=Z(R)\cdot I_n$$
and we want a morphism
$$K\to Z(R).$$
It suffices to find a morphism $$Z(R)\cdot I_n\xrightarrow\psi Z(R).$$
We can take the map that sends a matrix to the element in its left upper corner. (This is indeed a ring morphism, as is easily checked.)